# how to derive the mean square risk equation

Tags: machine-learning

I notice there is an equation
$$E_{X,Y\sim P}[(f(X)-Y)^2] = E_{X\sim P_X}[(f(X)-E[Y|X])^2] + E_{X,Y\sim P}[(Y-E[Y|X])^2]$$
LHS = $E[(f(X)-E[Y|X])^2] + E[(Y-E[Y|X])^2] + 2E[(f(X)-E[Y|X])(E[Y|X]-Y)]$

I know $E(E[Y|X]-Y)) = 0$, but how to see $f(X)-E[Y|X]$ and $E[Y|X]-Y$ are independent?

Comment: Did they give the assumption that E(Y|X) = f(X)?

Comment: I don't think so. E[Y|X] should be the bayes decision function.

Comment: I mean you go back to that writing and check if the author specified what is f(X).

Comment: f(X) is just a decision function. Not specified

Comment: $E[(f(X)-Y)^2] = E_X[(f(X)-Y)^2]  \text {  or   }E_Y[(f(X)-Y)^2]$?

Comment: I have edited it. This result has been shown in many places and it seems very straightforward. But I can't find the proof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$E_X\left\{E_{Y|X}[(f(X)-E_{Y|X}[Y|X])(E_{Y|X}[Y|X]-Y)]\right\}$$
$$=E_X\left\{(f(X)-E_{Y|X}[Y|X])E_{Y|X}(E_{Y|X}[Y|X]-Y)\right\} $$
$$=E_X\left\{(f(X)-E_{Y|X}[Y|X])(E_{Y|X}[Y|X]-E_{Y|X}(Y))\right\} $$
$$=E_X\left\{(f(X)-E_{Y|X}[Y|X])(E_{Y|X}[Y|X]-E_{Y|X}(Y|X))\right\} $$
$$=E_X\left\{(f(X)-E_{Y|X}[Y|X])0\right\} $$
$$=0$$
The key step is that $f(X)-E_{Y|X}(Y|X)$ is function of $X$ and has no $Y$ involved, So in the first step when $E_{Y|X}$ is performed, $f(X)-E_{Y|X}(Y|X)$ is a constant in term of $Y$ and can be separated.

Comment: Thank you very much!!!!